# Safe[ish] shutdown without the shutdown command

Tags: boot, shutdown

For my needs, I have to execute something (take a picture) early in the boot process, and then shut down the machine as quickly as possible.

Right now, I have a script that does exactly that, it takes the picture about 18 seconds after a reset, and then it issues a `shutdown now` command, which takes ~6-8 seconds to bring the system down. Right now I am just testing ideas, but in the end it will pull up some GPIO pin which will cause an Arduino to cut off the raspi power.

So I will have to write my own shutdown routine, which I guess it should do a `sync`, unmount the root fs, and then pull up that GPIO.
Is there anything else that I should do to safe[ish]ly shut it down?